# How to enter constants as an input in Java

Tags: java, integer, constants

I have been programming in Java and I was using the constant `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in my calculations in solving programming problems.

I was wondering if there was a way for Java to interpret `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (system defined constants) when entered as input by the user without doing the obvious string comparisons.

Currently I am using the constants as:

```
int MAXIMUMINTEGER = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int MINIMUMINTEGER = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

I would want to use them as follows:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
int number = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("The number entered is : " + number);
```

In the output console:

```
Enter a number: Integer.MAX_INT
The number entered is : 2147483647
```

I am looking at ways to make java understand defined constants as user input.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: No, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Quick Suggestion: Use `ALL CAPITAL` letters while naming constants to __differentiate__ them from __variables__!

Comment: You could compile it and call toString, but that seems more roundabout than doing string comparison.

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: @avr. Suggestion taken. Thanks.

Comment: Might be possible using reflection but someone smarter than me would have to show how that would work. Either way it is going to require at least a little custom code on your part.

Comment: I will look up on that @nhouser9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not easily possible unless the values are explicitly stated in your code (so the `String` comparison you mentioned).

However, there could be a hardcore solution using reflection mechanism, which is basically meta-access to classes and their fields. Still, you would need to parse the input as a field name, like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
String input = in.nextString();
Class klass = Class.forName("java.lang." + input.split("\\.")[0]);
Field field = klass.getField(input.split("\\.")[1]);
int number = field.getInt(klass);
System.out.println("The number entered is : " + number);
```

This would get the expected result for your input (provided you pass `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and not `Integer.MAX_INT`, as the latter is not a constant value).

I guess you *could* turn it into functioning code using `Integer.valueOf()` first and then parsing the `String` if the value is invalid.

Still, there are so many border cases that this would hardly be worth it in any imaginable scenario :-)

Comment: I have updated the code to actually compile if you want to test it ^^